# Expressing the maximum difference between Gaussian random variables? And the probability that it is within a given limit.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Say I have a set of independent Gaussian random variables:

$$
X = \left\{ X_1, ... , X_n \right\}
$$
where:
$$
X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(x_i \mid \mu_i,\sigma_i^2)
$$

I seek an expression (that can be evaluated) for the maximum difference between any pair of X_i.

Of course there are ${}^nC_2$ such pairs or:

$$
\frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}
$$

and the difference between any pair can be written:

$$
\Delta X = X_j - X_k
$$

where $j \ne k$ and $1 \le j \le n$ and $1 \le k \le n$.

Where $\Delta X$ is conveniently itself a Gaussian random variable of form:

$$
\Delta X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_j - \mu_k,\sigma_j^2 + \sigma_k^2) \mid \mu_j \ge \mu_k
$$

Where the condition is added simply to order $j$ and $k$ in any given pair (without it $\Delta X $ for a pair has no singular definition as it could just as well be defined with $\mu_k - \mu_j$).

The expression I seek, both to describe (express) and to evaluate in the context of a probability is the the maximum $\Delta X$ for the set $\left\{ X_1, ... , X_n \right\}$. I'm a tad stuck on both elegant expression of that and evaluation of it as a probability.

Going backwards if I can express:

$$
\Pr(\Delta X_i \le \epsilon) = \Phi\left(\frac {\epsilon-\mu_\Delta} {\sigma_\Delta}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac {-\epsilon-\mu_\Delta} {\sigma_\Delta}\right)
$$

where $\Phi$ is the Normal CDF and:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mu_\Delta &= \mu_j-\mu_k\\
\sigma_\Delta^2 &= \sigma_j^2+\sigma_k^2\\
\end{align*}
$$

And I could, clumsily perhaps express:

$$
\Delta X = \left\{ \Delta X_1, ... ,\Delta X_m \right\}\\
$$

where $m = {}^nC_2$, and I ask what is:

$$
\Pr\left(\Delta X_i \le \epsilon \, \forall i \in \left\{1,..,m\right\}\right)
$$

Can such a probability be written as a combination of the probabilities $\Pr(\Delta X_i \le \epsilon)$ or can new random variable be defined as some linear function of the $\Delta X_i$ that thus retains the Gaussian distribution and for which the probability $\Pr(X_{new} \le \epsilon)$ could be written as above (the difference between two Normal CDFs)

**Addendum**

It happens, that various authors offer a nomenclature for describing the ordering of a set such $\Delta X$ above. The ordered vector can be written:

$$
\Delta X = \left[ \Delta X_{(1)}, ... ,\Delta X_{(m)} \right]\\
$$

where:

$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta X_{(1)} &= \operatorname{min}(\Delta X)\\
\Delta X_{(m)} &= \operatorname{max}(\Delta X)\\
\Delta X_{(i)} &\le \Delta X_(i+1)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Which helps a little in expressing the goal here succinctly. That is, I am after:

$$
\Pr(\Delta X_{m} \le \epsilon)
$$

And it follows from the definition of $\Delta X_{(m)}$ that if it is less than $\epsilon$ that all the $\Delta X_i$ are.

What remains is to find a solution for that probability!

The crux of the problem of course is that $\Delta X_{m}$ is not easily defined, because all the $\Delta_i$ have distinct mean and variance and hence $\Delta X_{m}$ is not simply that with the largest mean ($\Delta X_i \mid \mu_i = \mu_{(m)}$).

There remains the hope, that there is a joint distribution that we can find which defined $\Delta X_{m}$ effectively.

**Addendum II**

I suspect that the field of Order Statistics:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

is very relevant here. In fact in terms of order statistics if we take the original set:

$$
X = \left\{ X_1, ... , X_n \right\}
$$

The order vector becomes:

$$
X = \left[ X_{(1)}, ... ,X_{(n)} \right]\\
$$

And we can define:

$$
{\rm Range}\{\,X_1,\ldots,X_n\,\} = X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}
$$

and are asking for $\Pr(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)} \le \epsilon)$.

The challenge remaining is that the elements of X are not IID (Independent and identically distributed), merely Independent and Normally Distributed (perhaps I can coin IND) and there is a suggestion that the Bapat–Beg theorem applies:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem

thought the puzzle remains, how? How that theorem can be applied to yield $\Pr(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)} \le \epsilon)$.

Comment: Are the $X_j$ independent?

Comment: We can assume they are yes. Whether that assumption is solid or not is another matter altogether. But indeed I forgot to mention the salient assumption of independence. Will amend.

Comment: Of course it is an interesting question to ask as well, if the $X_i$ are all independent are all the $\Delta X_i$ also perforce independent. I have an inkling yes, but am not sure I could prove that ;-).

Comment: I ran some simulations and I think this is a quite complicated problem if you want an analytical solution

Comment: The differences aren't in general independent. For example, suppose that $n = 3$. Then there are six possible differences and any two of them must have at least one component in common. E.g. $X_1 - X_2$ and $X_2 - X_3$ both involve $X_2$. This is a special case of the "maximum of correlated Gaussians." I agree that it's going to be hard if not impossible to say anything analytical that holds generally. In two dimensions, there's a known result: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139072/distribution-of-the-maximum-of-two-correlated-normal-variables

Comment: If you are looking for an upper bound, a simple one is $\Pr(2|X_i| < \epsilon \ \forall \ i \in \{1,2, \dots, m\})$ . I believe this also going to be more or less tight, atleast in terms with dependence on $\epsilon$.

Comment: I am fairly confident that the Bapat–Beg theorem applies in this case:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem

Though I have yet to digest and understand it. Thought to note the discovery for now. Moreover I suspect Order Statistics are very relevant and useful here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Answer (score 1):

The maximum difference between the $X_i$'s would be the largest minus the smallest.  In other words, we can use order statistics.  If I understand your question correctly, you want the probability distribution for $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$, where $X_{(1)}$ is the minimum of all the $X_i$'s, and $X_{(n)}$ is the largest.

$$f_{X_{(i)}, X_{(j)}}(x_i, x_j) = \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(j-i-1)!(n-j)!}\big[F(x_i)\big]^{i-1} \cdot [F(x_j)-F(x_i)]^{j-i-1}\cdot[1-F(x_j)]^{n-j}f(x_i)f(x_j)$$ when $i<j$, for all $x_i < x_j$.

Ross then writes the case where $i=1$ and $j=n$:

$$f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}}(x_1, x_n) = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!(n-1)!} \cdot [F(x_n)-F(x_1)]^{n-2}\cdot[1-F(x_n)]^{n-1}f(x_1)f(x_n)$$

From there it is messy integration to find the density of $X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$.

Comment: That's a brilliant insight.  Thanks. You mention Ross.  Can you provide more detail there,  a citation perhaps? It'll take me a moment to suggest this...

Comment: Sheldon Ross wrote several probability texts, the one I used is A First Course in Probability, Fifth edition, page 279 The same material is in Wackerly's et al, Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 7th edition, page 333.

Comment: Thanks heaps. It's worth adding that in Ross, it is section "6.6 Order Statistics" (as page numbers vary edition to edition apparently I have the 8th) and in Wackerly et. al. it is in section "6.7 Order Statistics". I shall read these and attempt to digest.

Comment: Can't edit the comment alas but int he first comment I mean "digest this" not "suggest this".

Comment: I have no read both sections in both texts and digested it on a first pass. The problem alas, which I have made more explicit in the original question, is that this result (and its derivation) is predicated upon $X_i $(in Ross's case), $Y_i$ (in Wackerly's case), $\Delta X_i$ (in my case), are identically distributed - where mine most definitively are not. They are all Gaussian yes, but have their particular and distinct $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, further complicating matters alas.

Comment: Ah, I see, I missed that detail.  The derivation will be significantly longer, but should still work if the densities are labeled distinctly.  I'd try it with 2 and then 3 variables and then $n$.  I'll give it a shot after work today.

Comment: I am fairly confident that the Bapat–Beg theorem applies in this case:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem

Though I have yet to digest and understand it. Thought to note the discovery for now. Moreover I suspect Order Statistics are very relevant and useful here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: And I have found M. Güngör, F. Özbey:
https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/download/article-file/105663
who provide a dense paper but crucially introduce the term innid (independent but not necessarily identically distributed) to contrast IID and present CDFs for the max and min, the range clearly being the difference between these. The problem is I don't follow their nomenclature well yet, and in the words of one writer this seems "computation intractable" ;-). More to the point deriving an expression for the range probability falling beneath a threshold from this seems challenging.

Comment: Looking rather complicated for now. Wonder if @RobertTheTutor made any progress. I have a number of papers yo digest now and may need to park that as a side project. It intrigues and interests me but the cost is rising ;-).

Comment: Unfortunately no progress here. I tried to find a way to rescale them by changing limits of integration, but the normal distribution is just too much of a pain to integrate with. I hoped to pair them up assuming an even $n$.  There are various special cases if additional assumptions are made about the $\mu$'s and $\sigma's$ but I haven't cracked anything noteworthy.